# How to access the content of value variable in Local Storage

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have to store the objects of this Class,

Page1.cs:

```
public class Connected
    {
        public static int connected;
        public static RootObject rootObjectCnx;
    }
```

but the problem is that I can't access the value variable content,this is my try:

```
 public static Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
....
  Connected c = new Connected();
  saveData(c);
...
     private void SaveData(Connected c)
            {
                localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
                localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] = c;
            }
```

then I have read it like this:

Page2.cs:

Object value = Page1.localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"];

```
    if (value != null)
    {

       //how can I access the value variable??

    }
```

my porblem is that I can't access the content of value variable,
any help please??
thanks for help

Update:
thanks Tommaso Scalici for your reply,I tried to affect the composite value to an other variable like this:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite =          (Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue)Page1.localSettings.Values["exampleCompositeSetting"];
 if (composite != null)
            {
                int tt = composite["intVal"]; //error here

               ...
            }

            else
            {
               ....
            }
```

the error is:

> Can not implicitly convert type 'object' in 'Int
>   '. An explicit conversion exists (a cast-is
>   it missing?)

Update2:
I get an other error at those lines:

```
  ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite = new Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue();
            composite["boolVal"] = myClassCnx.stateConnexion;(this variable is a bool)
            composite["intVal"] = Connected.connected; (this is an int variable)
            localSettings.Values["exampleCompositeSetting"] = composite;
```

> Informations WinRT : Error trying to serialize the value to be written
>   to the application data store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in that way you can only store primitive types (int, string and so forth). If you want to store complex object you have to use ApplicationDataCompositeValue (here MSDN documentation [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdatacompositevalue.aspx))

Otherwise if the type it's not very complex you can always serialize the instance into JSON and save the serialized string. But remember that the limit for simple settings values is 8K bytes (and 64K bytes for composite ones).

The class that you want to store must be marked as serializable like this:

using System.Runtime.Serialization;

```cs
[DataContract]
public class Connected
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Connected { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool StateConnection { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks Sir for your reply,but what about in this line: // Access data in composite["intVal"] and composite["strVal"]??I tried to put int tt = composite["IntVal"]; but I get an error

Comment: the values in settings are stored as an ICollection<object> 
that means that you have to do a cast each time you want to retrieve them, e.g.:

var intValue = (int)composite["IntVal"];
var stringValue = (string)composite["strVal"];

Comment: thanks again Sir I have done what You have propsed I have an other error now

Comment: in fact the problem was with a type that I have created,in there I get this error

Comment: The type that you created need to be marked as serializable, since WinRT internally serialize it to store it. I'm updating my answer to show how you should declare your class.